# Do you write your own CSS file for mobile-friendly layout?

Tags: css

I love Bootstrap which is a wonderful framework to create a modern and mobile friendly website. But it is a little too large and excessive to me. Currently I am trying to create some small websites. Would I get better off by writing my own CSS codes for the mobile friendly purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It's convenience for the visitor vs the developer.

Using the Bootstrap framework will cause the web developer to save time at the inconvenience of a slower site.

Remember, no matter how big the site, you're probably not even going to be using all of the functions.